# Python Regex with Paramiko

Tags: python, regex, paramiko

I am using Python Paramiko module to sftp into one of my servers. I did a `list_dir()` to get all of the files in the folder. Out of the folder I'd like to use regex to find the matching pattern and then printout the entire string.

List_dir will list a list of the XML files with this format

```
LOG_MMDDYYYY_HHMM.XML 

LOG_07202018_2018 --> this is for the date 07/20/2018 at the time 20:18
```

Id like to use regex to file all the XML files for that particular date and store them to a list or a variable. I can then pass this variable to Paramiko to get the file.

```
for log in file_list:
    regex_pattern = 'POSLog_' + date + '*'
    if (re.search(regex_pattern, log) != None):
        matchObject = re.findall(regex_pattern, log)
        print(matchObject)
```

the code above just prints: 
`['Log_07202018']` I want it to store the entire string `Log_07202018_20:18.XML` to a variable.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a fixed string, don't use regex.

```
search_str = 'POSLog_' + date

for line in file_list:
    if search_str in line:
        print(line)
```

Alternatively, a list comprehension can make list of matching lines in one go:

```
log_lines = [line for line in file_list if search_str in line]

for line in log_lines:
    print(line)
```

---

If you must use regex, there are a few things to change:

- Any variable part that you put into the regex pattern must either be guaranteed to be a regex itself, or it *must* be escaped.
- "The rest of the line" is not `*`, it's `.*`.
- The start-of-line anchor `^` should be used to speed up the search - this way the regex fails faster when there is no match on a given line.
- To support the `^` on multiple lines instead of only at the start of the entire string, the `MULTILINE` flag is needed.

There are several ways of getting all matches. One could do "for each line, if there is a match, print line", same as above. Here I'm using `.finditer()` and a search over the whole input block (i.e. not split into lines).

```
log_pattern = '^POSLog_' + re.escape(date) + '.*'

for match in re.finditer(log_pattern, whole_file, re.MULTILINE):
    print(match.string)
```

Comment: Definetely, can even simply use `if search_str in line`, supposed to be faster.

Comment: the string is fixed in the beginning part so it will always show POSLOG_MMDDYY_ but theHHMM at the end will change. Will for line in file_list: still print out? or does it have to be an exact match, no more no less?

Comment: You can answer this question by looking at the code.

Comment: Keep getting this error. 

    for match in re.finditer(log_pattern, file_list, re.MULTILINE):
  File "C:\Users\KXM4328\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 229, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you even using the regex solution? I thought the answer makes it clear that you should not use regex for this.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only print the matched part, just do `print(log)` instead and it'll print the whole filename.